# Synchronous Replication Setup on 2 Postgresql 9.2.1.4 machines

Tags: database, replication, postgresql-9.1

I am running synchronous replication on 2 Postgresql 9.2.1.4 machines (master and slave)

Here is the configuration:

**Master Parameters**

```
synchronous_commit=on
synchronous_standby_names = '*'
no synchronous_replication_timeout parameter, so 10 sec by default
no synchronous_replication parameter, so async by default
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 5
wal_keep_segments = 32
hot_standby = on
```

**Slave Parameters**

```
no synchronous_commit, so by default on 
no synchronous_replication_service parameter, so by default async 
max_wal_senders = 5 
wal_keep_segments = 32 
hot_standby = on
```

The application inserts records on Master and reads the from Master or Slave by using pgpool. Sometimes it happens that just after inserting the records the application does not see the inserted records (probably by reading from another db host as inserted ),
but when we check it afterwords the records are there in the database.

On 
http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Synchronous_replication#SYNCHRONOUS_REPLICATION_OVERVIEW
I found:
"If no reply is received within the timeout we raise a NOTICE and then return successful commit (no other action is possible)."

My Questions

1. a) Does it really mean that if the synchronous_replication_timeout
   (which is 10 second by default) on Master is exceeded and in any of three cases where

- the data did not reach the Slave or

  the Transaction was not commited on Slave or

  the Transaction was rolled back on Slave,

that the Master commits the transaction but the slave not at all?

If so then the transaction does not seem to be really synchronous...

1. b) What if I set on Master synchronous_replication_timeout=0 Will
   Master wait infinitly for Slave to Commit or Rollback and  in case
   slave commits, master commis too in case slave rollbacks, master
   rollbacks too?
2. What values should I set in

   synchronous_replication  (on master)
   = async (def) | recv | fsync | apply

and

```
synchronous_replication_service (on Slave)
= async (def) | recv | fsync | apply
```

in order to ensure I do have propper synchronous replication setup
(so I am sure that data is commited on both servers or rolled back on both)

Shoud they both be set to apply?

1. Is there any option to ensure that by using  synchronous replication
   on PosgreSQL 9.1.4  the data are commited on both master and slave 
   are commited at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The wiki page you referenced currently describes a patch implementing synchronous replication which wasn't committed, see here if you're interested:
  http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2010-12/msg02484.php

So the questions you have about GUCs "synchronous_replication_timeout" or "synchronous_replication_service" aren't relevant to released versions of PostgreSQL, since the version of synchronous replication which was eventually committed differed substantially from the one described in that wiki page. Sorry about that, and I'll see about getting that wiki page cleaned up. The information you want is at:
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html#SYNCHRONOUS-REPLICATION